# How to access React component directly from URL, and not only from internal links?

Tags: html, reactjs, react-router-dom

### UPDATE: Problem was fixed with adding `<base href="/">` in the head of the  root index.html.

I am setting up my first functional React webpage, where some of the purpose is to list out housing projects on a detail page based on the house id. This means that I typically have URL like this: [www.address.com](http://www.address.com), and [www.address.com/project/1](http://www.address.com/project/1), set up with react-router-dom. Works fine when clicking links internally on the page, but the problems arise when I'm trying to access the [www.address.com/project/1](http://www.address.com/project/1) (or 2 or 3 or x) page directly from the URL. The component partly loads, but it's of course not loading the <link> and <script> from the main app's index.html page, as I understand it has no clue about this index.html page existing at all. So optimally I should just force the component to use index.html when accessing [www.address.com/project/x](http://www.address.com/project/x).

So how do I proceed to get this in order? I'm not quite sure what code to share as relevant to solve the case, so bear with me on that.
There are some other topics on google, but I find none solving my problem. All answers seems too complicated as for such a trivial thing as accessing the page structure directly from an URL, so there must be a simple way, right? All webpages published needs this in order to be functional for the customer.

I have tried to Route like this in my App,js, but I'm stuck from here.

```
<Route path="/project/:id" element = { <Project /> } />
```

My logic says it must be a decent way to link up my component to use the index.html as a base when accessed from URL.

Comment: The index.html should have nothing to do with the issue here. What does your `<Project />` component look like? And what is the exact error your seeing?

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you mean by "The component partly loads, but it's of course not loading the <link> and <script> from the main app's index.html page"? If the app loaded and rendered anything at all on one of the sub-routes then the root index.html file that ***is*** your React app was returned and the app mounted. What is the `Project` component/page missing? Can you [edit] to include more relevant details and a more complete [mcve].

Comment: Drew Reese you have a point. Yes the content is loading, but the styles, bootstrap, jquery and all that stuff which is defined in index.html is apparently missing and not loaded. I will come back with an edit on my post for a better example later today.

Comment: I just solved this by adding <base href="/"> in the root index.html.

Answer (score 0):

to deserve you route `/project/:id`

you need to import useParams if you are using react-router-dom

```
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom'

export default function Project (props) {
  const { id } = useParams() // <-- here you can get variable id
  // const params = useParams() // <-- or full params Object

  return (
    <React.Fragment>My id is: {id}</React.Fragment>
  )
}
```

Comment: If you are using typescript (better for avoid every error type before execution) you will need to use your params like this: `const { id } = useParams<{id: string}>();`

Comment: I don't believe this addresses anything the OP asked about or mentioned in their post. I don't think the post is about accessing a route path parameter.